# Как лучше реализовать окно настроек в Android

Tags: java, android, settings

Меня интересует такой вопрос: я хочу реализовать в приложении настройки, смена размера текста, смена цвета текста, фона, шрифта и тд.

Как правильно и лучше реализовать это? Cоздать отдельное активити со своим макетом и из этого активити передавать значения в главное активити?

Подскажите кто знает, как оно должно быть и как сделать будет лучше.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Как правильно и лучше реализовать это?

Зависит от ситуации:

- если это какие-то локальные параметры, то можно отобразить экран изменения этих параметров в виде диалога над той активити, к которой эти параметры относятся;
- если параметры глобальные, то целесообразно будет использовать отдельную активити для их изменения.

Сами настройки можно сохранять в `SharedPreferences`.

Для экрана настроек существуют шаблоны: `PreferenceActivity` и `PreferenceFragment`.

Comment: То есть лучше создать отдельное активити для настроек?

Comment: @Tommy, Обновил ответ.